# How do I concatinate strings in attr

Tags: jquery, laravel

I want to concatenate strings in attr using `jquery`

I have already tried using `+` but it doesn't get the value of the variable:

```
 var job_id = $(this).attr('value');

   if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this? This will be removed permanently")){

      $(".job_delete").attr("href", '{{ route('job_delete','job_id') }}');

   }
   else{

      return false;

   }
```

I want to get the value of `job_id` not the text `job_id`. Any ideas on what I can try?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't pass in the string "job_id" and use the variable instead? But if you're using a templating language, which it looks like you are, you need that value on the *templating* side, not the client-side JS side.

Comment: I don't know how to pass the job_id variable in the attr. I can't concatenate it.

Comment: There’s no concatenation here, it’s a parameter to a method. You’re also confusing server-side and client-side code. PHP runs on the server, JS on the client.

Comment: But whenever I alert the job_id itself it is returning the job_id. Because it is in the value attribute.

Comment: Yes. On the *client*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass the Javascript variable value in PHP. But you can achieve this with a slightly different approach. There are other different ways to do it but I guess it is the simplest one to understand.

```
// Set your delete job url in the html
<a href="javascript:;" class="_delete" data-action="{{ route('job_delete', $jobId) }}">Delete</a>
```

Now do the following in the Javascript

```
$('.__delete').click(function(e) {
    var href = $(this).data('action');

    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this? This will be removed permanently")) {
       // Do whatever you want
       $(".job_delete").attr("href", href);
    }
    else {
       return false;
    }

});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I don't know what to put in //Do whatever you want. I tried it but it's not triggering the href.

Comment: Oh it's working now. I forgot to replace $(".job_delete").attr("href", href); the class in this code. Thank you so much!